# Play Video view in full screen mode

Tags: android, video

In Landscape mode video view is covering 3/4 part of screen . how to make it full screen?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play video in full screen, then just add these changes in your Androidmanifest.xml file. Just add these two lines in android manifest file:

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" 
 android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Like in my androidmanifest.xml file i have added it

```
  <activity
        android:name="com.appliconic.straminglivevideo.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```